# How do I change the amount of values shown on the x-axis of a pandas dataframe plot?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Once again I'm stuck in python: I can't find a nice way of representing my data.

I've got a bunch of discharges that I want to plot. However, when I do this the x-axis is too crowded with dates. How can I change the representation that it just shows years (or just a few months). My code is below, the figure of my current result is this:
[bargraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsUtK.png)

Thanks in advance!

```
time = pd.Series(pd.period_range('1/1/1970', 
freq='M', periods=12*12))

y = np.zeros(int(len(discharge)/3))
for i in range(int(len(discharge)/3)):
    y[i] = discharge.sum(axis=1)[i*3]

qdi_bar = pd.DataFrame()
qdi_bar['sum_discharge'] = y
qdi_bar.index = time

qdi_bar.plot.bar()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 1:** You can use this code with `matplotlib`:

```py
time = pd.Series(pd.period_range('1/1/1970', 
                                 freq='M', periods=12*12))
# Change to timestamps instead or period ranges (the latter cause a TypeError when used with pyplot)
time = time.apply(lambda x : x.to_timestamp())

y = np.zeros(int(len(discharge)/3))
for i in range(int(len(discharge)/3)):
    y[i] = discharge.iloc[i*3].sum()

qdi_bar = pd.DataFrame()
qdi_bar['sum_discharge'] = y
qdi_bar.index = time

#Plot with matplotlib.pyplot instead of pandas
plt.bar(qdi_bar.index, qdi_bar["sum_discharge"], width = 15)
plt.show()
```

This works fine for me: I am getting a barchart with only the years as ticks: [image: barchart made with pyplot]

Still you can apply the suggestion from the original answer and customize the result further with `matplotlib.dates`.

**Original post:** I don't know of any way to do this with `pandas.DataFrame.plot()`, but if you are willing to use `matplotlib` instead, then you can customize your x-axis as you like with [matplotlib.dates](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Matplotlib/api/dates_api.html#module-matplotlib.dates).

Comment: Worked out great except for the change in y[i], this I changed to: 
     y[i] = discharge.iloc[i*3].sum() 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh, of course! I had to change it because I generated my own data which was in a different shape. Editing back to your suggestion. Very welcome BTW!